# Saving Javascript Array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Hello i am quite new to javascipt so please explain things clearly. I am currently running a php page which includes:

upp.php

```
<script>
document.getElementById("data").value = localStorage.getItem('itemsArray');
</script>
```

this items array contains objects which is saved like this:

```
function save(){

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {};
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
    ,'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value
};
oldItems.push(newItem);
localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));}

$.post('upp.php',{ items: JSON.stringify(oldItems) }, function(response) {
    window.location.href = "upp.php";
```

the result of the page appears like this:

`[{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}]`

is there anyway i can save this information into PHP and split the data so I can manipulate it one at a time like a loop or something. For example:

1st time:

`{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}`

Next:

`{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}`

etc.

Thanks.

Comment: in upp.php you can use the `json_decode` function to turn it back into objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**upp.php:**

```
<?php 
$array = json_decode($_POST['items'], True);
foreach ($array as $key=>$line) {
    # $key is a number like 1173627548
    # and $Line is an array with methv, q1, q2, q3, q4, and comm
}
?>
```

That will show you the array it got from the JSON. Now you can work with the data.

Comment: Hey David i am getting a Undefined Index in my php page for the items. Any ideas? or do i have to import something like jQuery?

Comment: Test your jQuery AJAX call.